# How to copy files from mounted directory?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, rsync

I want to copy files from my mounted dir to my HOME directory.
My /mnt

```
/mnt# ls
'01 - Course Overview'                 '03 - Locating Elements & Navigating Dynamic Web Pages'  '05 - Overcoming Challenges and Increasing Efficiency'
'02 - Exploring Selenium with Python'  '04 - Loading Selenium Page Source into BeautifulSoup'   'Exercise Files'
```

How should rsync line look like?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Why were solutions from Google inadequate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
rsync -r /mnt/ $HOME/
```

This should copy the contents of /mnt into $HOME. You should probably select a subfolder in your $HOME directory though.

Comment: In most shells: [quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).